ImportError in Hugging Face Integration: `LocalEntryNotFoundError` when using Llama Index and transformers
I am working on an AI project with Llama Index and the transformers library, integrating Hugging Face models. Below is my code snippet:
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbedding
import tiktoken
from llama_index.core.callbacks import CallbackManager, TokenCountingHandler
from llama_index.core.service_context import ServiceContext
from llama_index.core.postprocessor import SentenceTransformerRerank
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceInferenceAPI

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'LocalEntryNotFoundError' from 'huggingface_hub.errors' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/errors.py)
During handling of the above exception, this occurred:
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.trainer because of the following error: cannot import name 'LocalEntryNotFoundError' from 'huggingface_hub.errors'
What I've tried:

Verified the installation versions of huggingface_hub and transformers.
Ensured the proper API key and models are set.
Upgrading the dependencies

%pip install --upgrade transformers huggingface_hub llama-index-llms-huggingface llama-index-llms-huggingface-api


Here’s how I resolved the issue. The error was caused by version mismatches between various libraries, particularly llama-index, transformers, huggingface-hub, and peft.
Solution:
I uninstalled the conflicting versions of the libraries and reinstalled specific compatible versions as follows:
Uninstall Conflicting Libraries:
pip uninstall llama-index-llms-huggingface -y
pip uninstall llama-index-llms-huggingface-api -y
pip uninstall huggingface-hub -y
pip uninstall peft -y

Install compatible version
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface-api==0.3.0
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface==0.4.0
pip install huggingface-hub==0.23.5
pip install peft==0.11.0

Key Points:

The issue was resolved by ensuring the compatibility of these libraries.
Downgrading peft to version 0.11.0 allowed it to work with huggingface-hub version 0.23.5.

